# knex.js / bookshelf.js - how to multiplay columns?

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to multiply two columns in bookshelf.js using the underlying knex.js syntax.

Here's the pure SQL I'd like to do (at least the `select` part):

```
select sum(quantity * price) as sum 
from products 
inner join orders_products on orders_products.product_id = products.id 
inner join orders on orders_products.order_id = orders.id  
where orders.id = 1
group by (orders_products.order_id)
```

Here's my query:

```
return new Orders().fetch({
    withRelated: [{
        'sum': function(qb) {
            /*
             how could I multiplay values here, i.e. 
             qb.sum('products.price * orders_products.quantity as sum');
            */
            qb.sum('products.price as sum');
            qb.groupBy('orders_products.order_id');
            qb.limit(1);
        }
    }, 'products', 'owner', 'assignedUsers', 'comments.user']
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.toJSON();
});
```

As commented in the code, I'd like to actually do this: `qb.sum('products.price * orders_products.quantity as sum');`

This of course doesn't work, since I get an error that there is no column named `products.price * orders_products.quantity`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at knex's .raw:  knex.raw('products.price * orders_products.quantity as sum')  -- Which you might be able to wrap inside of a .sum()

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but this actually produced an error. I got it to work by doing the following: `qb.select(knex.raw('sum (products.price * orders_products.quantity) as __sum'));`